# macOS に Anaconda をインストールすると、Python は複数インストールされた状態になる？

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

macbookにAnacondaを入れたのですが、これってPythonが重複して入っていますか？また、macのPythonを消してもPythonがつかえますか？

それと、なぜかわからないのですが、condaコマンドが使えません。どうしてですか？

Answer (score 2):

AnacondaはPythonのディストリビューションの一つですので、本家のPythonやMacにデフォルトで入っているpythonとは別にインストールされ、別の環境を構築します（手元の環境にないので多分ですが）。
システムに複数の `python`コマンドが存在する事になるので「重複」と言ってよいと思います。

Macデフォルトの`python`を消してもAnacondaでインストールした`python`コマンドは動くと思います。
しかし、他に動かなくなる物が沢山あると思いますよ。

インストール完了後に`conda`コマンドが使用できないのはPATHが通っていないからだと予想します。AnacondaのインストーラがPATH設定を`~/.bash_profile`に追加するようですが、どうなっていますか？

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
cat ~/.bashrc
echo $PATH
ls ~/anaconda/
```

などで状況を調査してみて下さい。